# What does floating point biased notation have to do with 2's complement?

Tags: computer-architecture, floating-point

During lecture the professor talked about Integer Compare for floats and kept mentioning two's complement.

What's the relation between them?

All I understand is that two's complement can take us from a number to its negative.

Answer (score 2):

IEEE 754 Floating point is a standard way of representing fractions in binary which does *not* use two's complement.  There's a discussion [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/why-floating-point-representation-uses-a-sign-bit-instead-of-2s-complement-to-i) about why that is.